# Codeigniter Session Class not displaying session variables set by other domain

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, facebook-login

In my site i have integrated facebook login. Site is developed using `CodeIgniter` framework. In facebook login, after authentication carried out by facebook, certain session variables are set by facebook in my domain such as `fb_appid_access_token` etc. I am using codeigniter's `SESSION CLASS`. What i have observed is that when I add `session_start` in  controller and use `print_r($_SESSION);`, the facebook sessions are visible in my `view page`. How to display all session variables set by other domains(facebook etc) in my domain using `CODEIGNITER SESSION CLASS`?

Answer (score 0):

In fact you should not use $_SESSION variabla in codeigniter. Probably you changed something inside of codeigniter core. Please can you give more information about your project. For example did you change anything in core, what is config, which class are you using for connecting to facebook etc...

Comment: yes! I totally want to avoid S_SESSION variable in CI. I followed this tutorial for facebook integration with CI http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2012/04/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-with-codeigniter-2-1/

Comment: you must not change basic logic in codeigniter. becouse it's whole system. you can look that for using facebook: http://chrismcleod.me/2011/11/25/using-the-facebook-php-sdk-with-codeigniter/